# Getting column information from system MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I am using the below SQL statement to retrieve the column information of a SQL Server database. I am getting more columns than there actually are I presume this is because of the system columns that are there also.

```
SELECT 
    c.name Field, 
    t.name Type,
    c.Precision, 
    c.Scale,
    c.max_length,
    c.is_nullable,
    c.collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('SOPOrders')
```

You will see the above query is producing ten Order Memos when in fact their should only be the one the var char I still want to be able to report back the prevision dataype maxlength and the null able factor so what is wrong with the above query please.

[image]

Comment: You have 7 columns in the Select of the query and 7 columns in the query results.  I look like the table in the database has a lot more columns and you can display more of the columns by adding then to the Select statement in the query.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a couple of reasons for that. First of all, you are joining `types` by wrong condition - you should use `user_type_id` instead of `system_type_id` on both sides. The latter gives you the underlying built-in type which was used as a basis of a user-defined one. See this query, for example:

```
select * from sys.types t where t.user_type_id != t.system_type_id;
```

Another possible thing is that the table has a sparse column set, but I might be wrong here.

And, of course, make sure you are actually querying the information about the right table - always include the schema name qualifier, along with the object name, such as:

```
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.SOPOrders')
```

Failure to do so will not result in duplication you observe, but following it will save you a lot of time trying to figure out the cause of intermittent inconsistencies, when you will have objects with the same name in different schemas.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `Information_Schema.COLUMNS` instead??

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOPOrders'
```

Or try to join on

```
ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
```

instead of

```
ON t.system_type_id=c.system_type_id
```